# Commandline install MSI takes too long

Tags: command-line, windows-installer

For some reason trying to install a msi executable trough commandline takes too long or never completes. The program is unsigned themes for windows that allows you to run unsupported themes on windows. Its available from here: [Download](http://www.uxstyle.com/builds/UxStyle_Core_jul13_bits.zip)

Im trying to install the 64bit version with:

```
start /wait "UxStyle Core x64.msi"
```

The whole batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off

net stop uxsms

IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "AMD64" call :install64
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" call :install32

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :UxStyleErr

takeown /f "%WINDIR%\Resources\Themes\Aero\aero.msstyles" 
icacls "%WINDIR%\Resources\Themes\Aero\aero.msstyles" /grant %USERNAME%:F"
ren "%WINDIR%\Resources\Themes\Aero\aero.msstyles" aero.msstyles.original
copy /y aero.msstyles "%WINDIR%\Resources\Themes\Aero\"

net start uxsms

echo Installation completed. Press any key to reboot or close this dialog if you want to restart later.
pause
shutdown /r /t 0
goto :eof

:install64
start /wait "UxStyle Core x64.msi"
goto :eof

:install32
start /wait "UxStyle Core x86.msi"
goto :eof

:UxStyleErr
echo An error occured while installing UxStyle Core. Installation will now quit.
pause
goto :eof
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using start /wait to launch the .msi file, I'd recommend calling msiexec.exe directly. You'll also be able to generate a log file which will help you diagnose what is going wrong. So I'd modify your `start /wait` commands to look like:

```
msiexec /i "UxStyle Core x64.msi" /l*v x64_installlog.txt
```

You can add `/passive` or `/quiet` to the command to show just a progress bar or run with absolutely no UI respectively.

Comment: Thank you. As per your instructions i got it working. Sorry about the delay in responding.

Answer (score 0):

Please read:

[Msiexec (command-line options)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

It looks like you are lacking the /QB or /QB switches to run without interaction.  Also consider adding REBOOT=R  to prevent them MSI from executing any unexpected reboots.